Understanding surjection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$
In a practise exam, the examinator asks:
"Give example of a surjection $g: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$".
The answer key suggests finding a surjection from $\mathbb R\rightarrow [0,\infty)^2$
which can be done by defining the decimal expansion of $x$ as
$x=\pm a_0a_1...a_n,b_0b_1...$
then letting $(u,w)$
$$
\begin{cases}
u=a_0a_2...a_n,b_0b_2b_4b_6....\\
w=a_1a_3...a_{n-1},b_1b_3b_5...
\end{cases}
$$
if $n$ is even and
\begin{cases}
u=a_0a_2...a_{n-1},b_0b_2b_4b_6....\\
w=a_1a_3...a_{n},b_1b_3b_5...
\end{cases}
if $n$ is odd.
Call this $q(x)$.
Then we simply define $f:[0,\infty)^2\rightarrow \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$
where $f(u,w)=(\ln u, \ln w)$ and defining $ln(0)=1$.
The surjection is then given by $g=q\circ f$
I do not understand why we do have to split into cases if $n$ is odd and even and I do not understand why we can skip every other number in the inputs. Can I get some help about that?

I don't understan d the notation.  What does $x=\pm a_0a_1\cdots a_n,b_0b_1$ mean?

@lulu I think they are using a decimal comma, so the $a_i$ form the decimal representation of the integer part and $b_i$ the decimal representation of the fractional part.

Nor do I understand the question.  Nobody is saying that you have to split into even and odd cases, the hint just points to one particular way of solving the problem.

@JaapScherphuis  I thought of that, but why does it stop at $b_1$?   I guess the OP meant for the $b's$ to continue...

@lulu It shouldn't of course. Also, the $f$ should be $f:[0,\infty)\color{red}{^2}\rightarrow \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ and $g=\color{red}{f\circ q}$.

@JaapScherphuis  Yes, this makes sense.

Variants of this question have been asked a lot on this site.  I've linked to one, but you can find others.

Yes sorry there were multiple errors in the OP. I will correct them immediately.
